# VFS: Cannot open root device when boot with an older kernel version

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-22.04

I got the following errors when I boot my ubuntu 22.04 server with kernel 4.18.
But it's bootable when I use other newer kernels (like 5.8)

Error Message:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Note:
I have checked:
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv filesystem is mounted on /
I have built initrd with command `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.18.0-041800-generic`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.